# clustering using non-negative matrix factorization (IntNMF): what to do about 'a dimension is zero' error

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, matrix-factorization

Using the `IntNMF` package I want to find clusters in a dataset.
My data is a sparse matrix (80-90% zeros) with subjects in the rows and features in the columns. For some reason, I get an error and I cannot figure out why or what to do about it.

```
library(IntNMF)

set.seed(4)
n <- 10
p <- 30
m <- matrix(sample(0:3, rep=T, size = n*p, 
                   prob = c(5,1,1,1)), ncol=p)
any(rowSums(m) == 0)  # no zero rows  
any(colSums(m) == 0)  # no zero columns
rankMatrix(m) == n    # full row rank

# finding the optimal number of clusters
opt.k <- nmf.opt.k(dat=m, n.runs=5, n.fold=2, k.range=2:4, 
                   result=TRUE, make.plot=TRUE, 
                   progress=TRUE)
```

The error I get is:

```
error in svd(X) : a dimension is zero
```

I assumed that sparsity is no problem, maybe it is. I am not very familiar with NMF or the `IntNMF` package yet, so any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the issue is with `IntNMF`, but it also fails for other seeds, as well as when using the default arguments for `nmf.opt.k`.

I would recommend checking out the [NMF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMF/index.html) library in the meantime instead.

I tested it out with your test matrix and it worked fine:

```
> nmf(m, rank=2)
<Object of class: NMFfit>
 # Model:
  <Object of class:NMFstd>
  features: 10 
  basis/rank: 2 
  samples: 30 
 # Details:
  algorithm:  brunet 
  seed:  random 
  RNG: 403L, 20L, ..., 961813654L [05ac8381a0361b9c9d54208dfe6a12cb]
  distance metric:  'KL' 
  residuals:  162.3778 
  Iterations: 480 
  Timing:
     user  system elapsed 
    0.047   0.000   0.046
```

There is also a section of estimating the rank of the factorization (selecting a `k`) in the the vignette for NMF (section 2.6).

Comment: Using the NMF library we get an NMF of the data without an error. However, this does not help me much, as I do not get the clustering and the comparisons (BIC etc.) for different numbers of clusters. Any ideas?

Comment: Also, while I could hard cluster each person, for example, using the maximum in each column of the weight matrix `W`, I assume that I will lose the model-based clustering approach implemented in `IntNMF`. Maybe there are better ways I am not aware of? :)

Comment: Yea, to get a single clustering of columns you can do `nmf_clusters <- apply(coef(result), 2, which.max)` where `result` is the output from a single call to `nmf()` -- for clustering the rows of `V`, you would indeed operate on `W` instead. `NMF` does have some functions to help plot and select a value of `k`, but nothing very sophisticated, as far as I'm aware. There is a 2008 review paper by [Devarajan](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1000029) which includes some discussion on approaches for model selection / robustness analysis that maybe helpful.